# .htaccess rule for adding .php extension and rule for fallback to route.php don't work together, only when used separately

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, blogs

Here is my `.htaccess` file, it's in the `/` directory and is working. I want to remove `.php` extensions from my site. So, I use the following rule to do so. `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`.

This works but I also want to redirect my blog articles which use dynamic links with this `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) route.php?blog=$1` these blogs pull an ID from a database and embed it into the URL and this works correctly.

My issue is that when I add the first paragraph code to remove `.php` extensions my blog redirect stops working. Below I will add my PHP code, for review in case I've done something wrong.

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) route.php?blog=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Error Documents
#ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
#ErrorDocument 403 /error_403.php
```

---

```
<?php
// open database //

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php");

$blog = explode("/",$_REQUEST['blog']);

$months = array('','January','Feburary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

switch(count($blog))
{
    
    case 3 : {

        if($blog[0]=="blog")
        {
            if(intval($blog[2]) > 0)
            {
                // get selected blog

                $sql = "select * from articles a, categories c where a.cat = c.catid and a.id = '".$blog[2]."' limit 0,1";

                $res = $db->query($sql);
                $rowcount = $res->num_rows;

                if($rowcount > 0)
                {
                    $id = $blog[2];
                    $blog = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

                    include($doc_path."/blog-single.php");
                }
            }
        } 

    } break;

}
```

---

#### `blog-single.php`

```
                    <?php
                        $sql = "select * from categories c, articles a, relatedposts r where r.related_blog = ".$blog['id']." and a.id = r.related_post and c.catid = a.cat order by a.datetime";
                        $rows = $db->query($sql);
                        $found = $rows->num_rows;
                        if($found > 0)
                        {
                    ?>
```

Comment: What should happen when you request the document root (ie. homepage)? Currently, neither of your rules handle this situation. Do you have an `index.php` file?

Comment: "Here is my `.htaccess` file, it's in the `/` directory and is working." - Your opening sentence is rather misleading, since (as described in the following paragraphs), the `.htaccess` code as posted is presumably _not_ working as intended. (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^?]*) route.php?blog=$1 
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

The "problem" here is that the first rule rewrites any request (that does not map to a file or directory) to `route.php`, passing the requested URL-path in the `blog` URL parameter. Consequently, the second rule (that appends `.php` to any URL-path that does not contain a dot) is never successful.

You need to reverse the rules and first check that the corresponding `.php` file exists before appending the `.php` extension. Any requests that are not mapped to a `.php` file will then fall through to `route.php`.

For example:

```
# Append ".php" extension if the ".php" file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Otherwise, drop through to "route.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) route.php?blog=$1 [L]
```

The original subpattern `[^?]*` is not necessary, since the query string is not passed in the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

---

*Aside:*

Note that neither of these rules handle requests to the document root (ie. the homepage) - as with your original directives. In other words, what do you expect to happen with a request for `https://example.com/`? Should this also be rewritten to `route.php` (is it already)? If so, then set the `DirectoryIndex` directive accordingly. For example, at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex route.php
```

Note that this will result in any request for the "homepage" being sent to `route.php`, but without the `blog` URL parameter (it would be empty anyway).

**UPDATE:** Although, looking at your PHP script, it doesn't look like you are expecting the document root (ie. an empty URL-path) being handled by `route.php` (your first script I assume)? In fact, your script would seem to expect 3 URL path segments only? In which case, you should consider making your regex more restrictive in `.htaccess` to prevent your script being unnecessarily called. This will allow the request to fall through to Apache's 404 error document.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer. To comment on your update my homepage is index.php and the site was automatically going there by default. But I have taken your advice and added "DirectoryIndex index.php" to the top of my .htaccess file. 

---

Your solution worked and I've added to my project as well as marking you the best answer. Thank you for taking your time to solve this problem for me, I plan on learning more about the .htaccess stuff in the future for different things. Hope you have a good day =)